# Fallout of cookie size exceeding the size allocated in a browser

Tags: http, browser, cookies

What happens if the size of cookies exceeds the size allocated for cookies in a browser?

Comment: @pharalia Maybe somebody already did? :)

Comment: I tried. But I did n't see any difference as an end user. I don't know what will happen to the other cookies that were already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the entire cookie cannot be stored, the cookie won't be stored at all (at least, not in a compliant implementation). From [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#section-5.3), Section 5.3:

> The information in a Set-Cookie2 response header MUST be retained in its entirety.  If for some reason there is inadequate space to store the cookie, it MUST be discarded, not truncated.